# How do I send the user a message when using php with header for forcing download

Tags: php, content-disposition

php application creates a file for user to download, which works perfectly. I want to give user guidance on downloading file and the number of entries in the file. If I include any output after sending the headers nothing is displayed to the user.

I've tried using cookies. Here's an excerpt of code...

```
...
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=myfile.txt");
readfile('tempfile.txt');
?>
<html>
<body>
<p>The file contained<?php count($VEVENTS)?> events.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't do that on the same page. Do a page with explanation with a redirect to the download page.